# Reverting Plugins within Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, backup, database-backups

After backing up my Wordpress installation (MySQL databases via phpMyAdmin, and the entire front end website via FTP) I updated a handful of plugins, which resulted in an important aspect of the website to fail.

The plugin I believe is responsible is 'Advanced Custom Fields', updated from 2.0.5 to 3.5.8.1. When I updated this plugin I got the notification:

"Advanced Custom Fields v3.5.8.1 requires a database upgrade (why?). Please backup your database, then click Upgrade Database." This was completed successfully.

As I've been unable to solve the problem I'm looking to restore my Wordpress installation from the backup. My question is what will be required to do this? Do I need to restore files from the FTP backup as well as the various mySQL databases?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback guys. I resolved this issue by completely deleting the plugin via FTP and using the developers Wordpress plugin page to download the prior version. Once installed everything snapped back into place. I didn't do anything to revert the database (despite this apparently being updated), and everything seems to work anyway.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress has instructions on how to restore from backup.  See them [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Restoring_Your_Database_From_Backup).

Load your themes (front end website as you call them) via FTP the same way you backed them up.

As for the plugins, you can try to download previous versions from the developer.  However do keep in mind if any create tables, those -I assume- should be restored in the first step.  As far as I know plugins do not create databases as you state, they may create tables within the current instalation of wordpress.

Did you by chance download anything outside the themes folder in your FTP?  I would imagine you can put the files back in there as the tables should be restored when you do the first step above.

That's how I would approach it, haven't done it so try on your own risk.

Another idea is to work with your host to get the files.  Mine at least does weekly backups to tape and they charge $15 to restore.

Answer (score 0):

If you backed up all the files and database (there is only one) then it should be no problem at all to revert it to where it was and thereafter only upgrade the plugins that were able to be upgraded.

You can find a solution to the Advanced Custom Fields issue by deploying the copy of the site on a dev server and tackling it there.

This of course depends on what you mean by the 'front end website'. The theme, the wp-content directory, or all files? Did you backup the plugins directory?